# Authorization using Metamask - Signing and validating - can you find any weaknesses in this approach?

Tags: metamask, javascript, signature, cryptography, java

I would like to develop a webapp (frontend: ReactJs, backend: Spring Boot) in which users can interact without logging in in the traditional sense of the word (username + password) but instead using Metamask for proving their identity.

Can you guys find any weaknesses in the following approach:

1. Client requests a nonce from the server `/nonce?publicAddress={metamaskAddress}`
2. Server generates a UUID for a specific Metamask address and stores it with a short TTL and returns it to the client
3. Client signs the nonce via Metamask
4. Client makes a request putting the signed nonce and the Metamask address in the headers
5. Server verifies that the Metamask address that signed the nonce is the same of the one sent in the headers and that the nonce is not expired

Client code (using ethers library)

```
        if (!window.ethereum) {
            throw new Error("No crypto wallet found. Please install it.");
        }
        await window.ethereum.send("eth_requestAccounts");
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);

        const signer = provider.getSigner();
        const address = await signer.getAddress();

        const nonceResponse = await fetch(`/nonce?userId=${address}`, {
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });

        const nonce = await nonceResponse.text();

        const signature = await signer.signMessage(nonce);

        await fetch("/doSomething", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": signature,
                "Public-Address": address,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify("data"),
        });
```

Server side - validation code taken from [sridharreddyu/web3-java-snippets](https://github.com/sridharreddyu/web3-java-snippets/blob/main/src/main/java/com/web3/java/example/Web3SignatureVerification.java)

```
    @PostMapping("/doSomething")
    public void doSomething(
            @RequestHeader(value = HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String signedNonce,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Public-Address") String publicAddress,
            @RequestBody String body) {

        String originalNonce = nonceService.getNonceForAddress(publicAddress)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));

        boolean verified = verifySignature(
                publicAddress,
                signedNonce,
                originalNonce
        );

        if (verified) {
            // do something with the body
        } else {
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    
    public static boolean verifySignature(String address, String signedMessage, String originalMessage) {
        String decryptedAddress = getAddressUsedToSignHashedPrefixedMessage(signedMessage, originalMessage);
        decryptedAddress = "0x" + decryptedAddress;

        return address.equalsIgnoreCase(decryptedAddress);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private static String getAddressUsedToSignHashedPrefixedMessage(String signedHash, String originalMessage) {
        String r = signedHash.substring(0, 66);
        String s = "0x" + signedHash.substring(66, 130);
        String v = "0x" + signedHash.substring(130, 132);

        String publicKey = Sign.signedPrefixedMessageToKey(
                        originalMessage.getBytes(),
                        new Sign.SignatureData(
                                Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(v)[0],
                                Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(r),
                                Numeric.hexStringToByteArray(s))
                )
                .toString(16);

        return Keys.getAddress(publicKey);
    }
```

(please ignore the SneakyThrows)

Thank you for reading this far - any comment/suggestion/criticism is appreciated :)